# Python thinks that psycopg2 DictRow is list (At least that's what it looks like)

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have some code that originally looked like this (it's part of a for loop that iterates through the results of a query):

```
title['name'] += 'x'
```

I sometimes get the following exception (always on the same row):

```
<class 'psycopg2.extras.DictRow'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rtk_film_nos.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "rtk_film_nos.py", line 150, in main
    title['name'] += 'x'
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I changed the code to be more verbose:

```
foo = title['name']
foo += 'x'
print type(title)
title['name'] = foo
```

The exception changed to:

```
<class 'psycopg2.extras.DictRow'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rtk_film_nos.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "rtk_film_nos.py", line 150, in main
    title['name'] = foo
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

If I wrap the code in a try/except it will quite happily print the contents of title['name'].

I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. It seems that for some reason python (v2.6.6) is deciding to treat the dict as a list but I have no idea why.

Comment: What version of Psycopg2 is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DictRow` class is a subclass of `list`, and [until version 2.3.0](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/commit/0ad7483a2bff6dd76843b31aa592877d96d6ea39) you could not use it to assign to elements by name.

You can work around this by looking up the column index directly:

```
title[title._index['name']] = foo
```

or, for your augmented assignment:

```
title[title._index['name']] += 'x'
```